# Remove indent in subsubsection heading

Tags: sectioning, indentation

I wish to remove the indent created by Latex at the start of the sub-sub-section heading 
**'Confidence Set'**, consider the below MWE

```
\documentclass[journal,onecolumn,11pt, peerreview]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\ifCLASSOPTIONcompsoc
    \usepackage[caption=false, font=normalsize, labelfont=sf, textfont=sf]{subfig}
\else
\usepackage[caption=false, font=footnotesize]{subfig}
\fi
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\begin{document}
\title{Place holder title}

\author{
\IEEEauthorblockN{Ishank Juneja}
}
\maketitle

\section{Placeholder}
\subsection{Placeholder}
%%
% Wish to remove indent created in next line 
%%
\subsubsection{\textbf{\underline{Confidence Set}}}
We denote this set as $C^*$.\\
Say, the support of r.v. $X$ has n indices 1,2,\ldots,n. Then, to find $C^*$, we\\
(i) First sort the empirical p.m.f. in descending order and obtain the sorted indices as $q_1,q_2,\ldots,q_n$.\\
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i = 1}^{k}p(x_i) > 1 - \epsilon    
\end{equation}
Thus, the confidence interval is the minimal such interval whose cumulative probability is greater than (1 - $\epsilon$) where $\epsilon$ is a small number, and is modelled as a Hyper-Parameter.\\
\end{document}
```

The output produced is:

[image]

I wish to remove the indent at the start of line 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

re-def `\thesubsubsectiondis`

Place this command before `begin{document}`

```
\def\thesubsubsectiondis{\unskip\arabic{subsubsection})}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, this removes the indent but it also removes the closing parenthesis after 1 i.e. 1) becomes 1 . Any way we can keep the ) or add a . instead of the ) ?

Comment: i update my answer with the closing parenthesis. You can add `)` or `.` or what ever you like after `\unskip\arabic{subsubsection}`